# File sharing problem with Python inside Excel

Tags: python, windows, excel, vba, file-io

I have python 2.6 script that creates a bunch of csv files on windows. 
This script can be run stand alone or inside Excel via VBA shell command. 
There are no problems when runs as stand alone, followed by VBA script.

When I run script inside Excel with a shell call.  I have file sharing problems.
The Script creates runs, close files

```
 fw = open(fn, "wb")
 fw.write(....)
 fw.close()
```

at the end of script I have:

```
os._exit(1)
```

Then Excel VBA does its stuff with the files. This gives error messages.

The error msg:

```
"FILE Now Available"

....is now avaiable for editing. 
Choose read-write to open it for editing.
```

The script is multitheaded....

Comment: why os._exit ? why not sys.exit? os._exit: Exit to the system with specified status, without normal exit processing.

Comment: chg to sys.exit(1), same problem.

Comment: On the other hand, I'm not familiar with VBA but "File Now Available" does not seem an error message...

Comment: "File Now Available" stops VBA script asks for selection of read-write or cancel. I stopped system dialogs via VBA-- no help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a delay after the shell call (doEvents or sleep(100) might work) to allow the OS to properly close the file and remove all pointers to the file.